# removeAllObjects crashes app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsarray

I want to clear my array, what i did is,

I have tableview view in my app, first i am fetching data from server and loading it in tableView.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

  //fetching data from server using background thread and storing it in array called (msg_array)
  [table reloadData];

}
```

when last row comes on screen i want to fetch new data from server and i want to display it,

```
-(void)LoadMoreData{ //this method gets fire when last cell is on screen 

    if ([msg_array count]>0) 
    {
        [msg_array removeAllObjects];  //crashes here
    }

}
```

This gives the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeAllObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Why does it cause a crash:

The array is allocated like this:

```
msg_array = [dictShow copy];
```

dictshow contains the data and copying it to msg_array and dictshow is mutabledictionary

(Taken from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853974/916299))

Comment: is msg_array NSArray or NSMutableArray?? Because NSArray does not have a method called removeAllObjects.Hence the crash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> '-[__NSArrayI removeAllObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This means that the array doens't have the method you're trying to call. That's because it is an immutable array (`NSArray`), not mutable (`NSMutableArray`).

Either make it mutable if you want to mutate it. Or, replace:

```
[msg_array removeAllObjects];
```

with:

```
msg_array = @[];
```

---

Based on your comment, the array should be mutable. That means that you have a mutable property / instance variable, but that you're creating an immutable instance to store into it. Find that location and update it (to create / return a `mutableCopy` at least).

Comment: it's Mutable only... declared this way `NSMutableArray *msg_array` in .h file

Comment: But where do you create an instance and assign it? That is likely where your problem is...

Comment: `msg_array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Could you post the code where you populate it with data?

Comment: That is the only place you ever assign `msg_array`?

Comment: dictshow contains the data and copying it to msg_array and dictshow is mutabledictionary `msg_array = [dictShow copy];`

Comment: copy] returns NSArray, here is your problem. Replace it with mutableCopy].

Comment: Change `copy` to `mutableCopy`... You description is strange though, copying a dictionary to an array? Bad naming hopefully...

Comment: it works but facing another problem... when i reload new data and reloads my table it removes old data from tableview.. like this http://i.imgur.com/eoN95pD.png

Comment: see my tableview i lost my old cells

Comment: Did you reload the table after removing content from `msg_array` (which is presumably your data source)?

Comment: `if ([msg_array count]>0) {
        [msg_array removeAllObjects];
    }

//Fetch and get data into array..

array = [dict mutableCopy];
[table reloaddata];`

Comment: if you define NSMutableArray with copy property, you will get this error:
@ property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *array;
instead use strong property:
@ property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are trying to modify a immutable array, you have two options here:

```
msg_array = @[];
```

OR

```
NSMutableArray *mutableMessageArray = [msg_array mutableCopy];
[mutableMessageArray removeAllObjects];
msg_array = [mutableMessageArray copy];
```

I prefer the first option as its neater, but if you need to do any other modifications of the array the latter option might be best for you.

NB:

Check how you declare `msg_array`, can you post that code?

Comment: `msg_array = [dictShow copy];` dictshow contains the data and copying it to msg_array and dictshow is mutabledictionary

Comment: Change copy to mutableCopy! [dictShow mutableCopy]

Answer (score 1):

`__NSArrayI`, looking carefully at this bit, we can see it's suffixed with an `i`. This `i` means the array is `i`mmutable and can't be changed.

You possibly want to use an `NSMutableArray`

> `msg_array = [dictShow copy];` dictshow contains the data and copying it to msg_array and dictshow is mutabledictionary

This is very strange! I expect that calling `copy` on a dictionary would always return a dictionary. Unless you are mistaken there, I can only imagine that either the dictionary's keys or its values are being returned.

I think you *might* have meant mutable array; assuming you did, the call to `copy` returns an immutable object, try `[dictShow mutableCopy]` instead

Comment: it's Mutable only... declared this way `NSMutableArray *msg_array` in .h file

Comment: How are you allocating that array? Can you show us the bit that looks like: `msg_array = ...`

Comment: `msg_array = [dictShow copy];` dictshow contains the data and copying it to msg_array and dictshow is mutabledictionary

Answer (score 1):

`msg_array` could be immutable thats why it is crashing. `removeAllObjects` is only for `NSMutableArray`

Comment: it's Mutable only... declared this way `NSMutableArray *msg_array` in .h file

Comment: Even if you are declaring it as `NSMutableArray`, check wether you are assigning a NSArray to it

Comment: `msg_array = [dictShow copy];` dictshow contains the data and copying it to `msg_array` and dictshow is mutabledictionary

Answer (score 0):

msg_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_MoodsArray].mutableCopy;